# Is it possible to determine the left/right plane equations of a frustum, given the near plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

If I am given four vertex points of the near plane that results from cutting the head of a pyramid off, is it possible to find the equation of the planes of the frustum to the left and right which are supposedly perpendicular to the near plane? Is it also possible to get the 4 vertex points of the far plane of the frustum if i know the field of view and height of the pyramid?

I ask this because I am having trouble trying to get all 6 planes of the frustum, and all I have is just the information listed above. So I am trying to figure out a way to determine them starting from a simple approach.

Comment: With the usual kind of rectangular pyramidal frustrum http://r3dux.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/frustrum.jpg If you know where is the eye and the near (rectangular) face, then yes you know the left/right plane. Did you mean 4 points defining the near (= front clipping) face, and the eye at the origin ?

Comment: And what do you want is to compute the $4\times 4$ projection matrix ? (homogeneous coordinates)

Comment: If you have the projection matrix, you can recover the bounding planes of the frustrum. They are the sums and differences of the first three rows with the last one.

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, I do know where the eye is and the near face, but I have googled and looked on youtube but no success on the technique used to get the planes. Can you kindly, let me know where I can learn how to do this or give an example with simple numbers?

Comment: Assuming the eye is at origin for simplicity, can you show me an example of how to derive on of the planes ?

Comment: @amd I only have the simple perspective projection matrix, not the fancy matrix that also includes turning the frustum into a cube.

Comment: You need to understand how to use a $4 \times 4$ projection matrix for projecting a point on the screen.

Comment: And what does that look like? Instead of making us guess exactly what you’re working with, add more context to your question. It may turn out that the solution to your problem is as simple as realizing that if you have the four corners of the near face, then you also have the four edges of the frustrum, which taken pairwise define the side planes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have a point $P  =\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z  \end{pmatrix}$ in your 3d scene. Add a $1$ to get $P' = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}$.
- Multiply $P'$ with the projection matrix $\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -d  \end{pmatrix} $
  to get $P'' = \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \\ z \\ z-d  \end{pmatrix}$
- Divide $P''$ by $w''= z-d $ to get $P''' = \begin{pmatrix} x/(z-d) \\ y/(z-d) \\ z/(z-d) \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}$
- If $x'',y'',z'' \in [-1,1]$, print the point at the position $(x'',y'')$ on the screen.

Can you find back the position of the 9 points of the frustrum from those transformation ?